# Thread after push button in Android and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanna run a thread after push a button in a fragment , i did like this:

```
btn!!.setOnClickListener {
        activityCallback!!.runOnUiThread(Runnable {

            Thread.sleep(10000)

            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        })
}
```

but after push the button, all of elements lock till time finish and anything not work

how can i run a thread after push a button without locking ?

thanks

Comment: With Handler, you can post delayed runnable.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Doing `Thread.sleep(10000)` inside of `runOnUiThread` (and `Handler().post`) will lock ui thread.

**Solution**

Instead of runOnUiThread, you need to use `Thread` class.

```
button9.setOnClickListener {
            Thread {
                Thread.sleep(10000)
                runOnUiThread(Runnable { Toast.makeText(this@DebugActivity, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
            }.start()
        }
```

**How does it work?**

1. run `Thread.sleep(10000)` inside of `Thread {}.start()`
2. run `Toast.makeText(...).show()` in `runOnUiThread` because showing toast need UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach would be to use Handler with delay. please find the code below

```
btn!!.setOnClickListener{
    Handler().postDelayed({
        Toast.makeText(context,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    },10000L) // delays the execution for 10s

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use coroutine to achieve that. As Threads are usually expensive, coroutine is more lighter way of doing threading. For the question, we have to do two  things

1) You have to delay the thread non-blockingly

2) Toast has to be shown on UI Thread

```
btn!!.setOnClickListener {
      GlobalScope.launch {
         delay(10000L)
         withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
             Toast.makeText(context,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }
   }
}
```

So in the code above

1)`GlobalScope.launch` - starts a dispatcher worker thread  and delays the execution for 10000 ms using `delay(10000L)`

2) once the delay is done, we are switching back to main thread using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main){` and displaying the toast inside it.